# HTML/PHP Fileupload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

firstly I know this question was answered multiple times here but none of these solutions worked for me.

It's not really hard and I tried out different things now but nothing seems like working for me. I sliced the code to a minimum to keep it simple.

My Code on html side:

```
    <form action="processParticipant.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
        <input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" type="file">
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
```

Now I would handle the file data in on my server to save it as a blob on my DB.
But now $FILES seems like to be not filled... $_POST["name"] is reachable...
tried something like this.

My Code on Serverside:

```
    $filename = $_FILES['filebutton']['name'];
    $filetype  = $_FILES['filebutton']['type'];
    $filetmp_name = $_FILES['filebutton']['tmp_name'];
    $fileerror = $_FILES['filebutton']['error'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['filebutton']['size'];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's in `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: What @shukshin.ivan said, and also check your PHP.ini to see if file uploads are enabled... `file_uploads = On`

Comment: - file_uploads are enabled
- $_FILES return this ->
Array ( [filebutton] => Array ( [name] => Example.txt [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno where my issue was.
But i solved it like this now!

```
    try {

        $file = $_FILES['filebutton'];

        // Watchout for errors while uploading.
        switch($file['error']){
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
        }

        // Check file_size
        if ($file['size'] > 5000000) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        }

        // check file_type
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
            $finfo->file($file['tmp_name']),
            array(
                'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'png' => 'image/png',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
            ),
            true
        )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
        }


        $type = pathinfo($file['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        $data = $base64;

    }
    catch (RuntimeException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```